# How to search in redis? (php)

Tags: php, redis

I see many examples about storing data and read it from Redis.

```
$redis->set("tutorial-name", "Redis tutorial"); 
$redis→get("tutorial-name");
```

But I dont know how to search in it. How to do searches like it was a MYSQL-LIKE command?

Comment: Redis is a key value storage. You should not even try to search.

Comment: Refer [`this doc`](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/) for searching or querying.

Answer (score 1):

In Redis, there's no direct equivalent to SQL's LIKE operation. Redis is primarily a key-value store, and its operations are tailored around efficient key-based access rather than complex querying capabilities like in relational databases.

However, there are some ways to perform search-like operations:

Using Keys:
If you have a known pattern for your keys, you can utilize the KEYS command to find keys that match a particular pattern.

```
$keys = $redis->keys("tutorial-*");
```

This will return all keys that start with "tutorial-". Note that in a production environment with a large dataset, the KEYS command can be resource-intensive and may degrade performance. For these scenarios, consider using the SCAN command, which is a cursor-based iterator.